# CakePHP 1.3 inflections?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Where to put custom inflections in CakePHP 1.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inflections.php has been removed in CakePHP 1.3, I have taken a section out of the 1.3 migration guide which should explain:

### Loading custom inflections

inflections.php has been removed, it was an unnecessary file hit, and the related features have been refactored into a method to increase their flexibility. You now use

```
Inflector::rules() to load custom inflections.
Inflector::rules('singular', array(
    'rules' => array('/^(bil)er$/i' => '\1', '/^(inflec|contribu)tors$/i' => '\1ta'),
    'uninflected' => array('singulars'),
    'irregular' => array('spins' => 'spinor')
));
```

Will merge the supplied rules into the infection sets, with the added rules taking precedence over the core rules.

[Source](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/13-migration-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Its under /app/config/inflections.php.

Comment: Sorry. Thought you were talking about CakePHP 1.2. In 1.3, you must define them in app/config/bootstrap.php using Inflector::rules().